# How to add gradient to button in Xamarin.Forms using CSS

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.forms-styles

Add gradient to button CSS in Xamarin.Forms.

I have idea of doing it using custom renderer, but is there a way to do it using CSS.

Answer (score 0):

Please find Below link.

I'm pretty sure this is **exactly** what you want

[Link](https://github.com/jesulink2514/XF-GradientButton)

Not sure if you researched anything before asking this
Here's some links on this topic after one search.

[1](https://medium.com/@benetskyybogdan/gradient-background-for-your-xamarin-forms-app-6d7e46fba558)

https://github.com/mgierlasinski/MagicGradients

> Gradients in CSS
>   If you want to use Magic Gradient for 100% and don’t want to import any CSS files into your project, you may try  — Inline CSS 
>   What? Inline CSS? What the ****? — This means that you have some string inline in XAML or in resources under some key, that string has special prefix and postfix in his value and parsed by Xamarin.Forms in the same way as other CSS from files.

```
<magic:GradientView VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
    <magic:GradientView.GradientSource>
        <magic:CssGradientSource>
            <x:String>
                <![CDATA[
                    linear-gradient(242deg, rgba(195, 195, 195, 0.02) 0%, rgba(195, 195, 195, 0.02) 16.667%,rgba(91, 91, 91, 0.02) 16.667%, rgba(91, 91, 91, 0.02) 33.334%,rgba(230, 230, 230, 0.02) 33.334%, rgba(230, 230, 230, 0.02) 50.001000000000005%,rgba(18, 18, 18, 0.02) 50.001%, rgba(18, 18, 18, 0.02) 66.668%,rgba(163, 163, 163, 0.02) 66.668%, rgba(163, 163, 163, 0.02) 83.33500000000001%,rgba(140, 140, 140, 0.02) 83.335%, rgba(140, 140, 140, 0.02) 100.002%),linear-gradient(152deg, rgba(151, 151, 151, 0.02) 0%, rgba(151, 151, 151, 0.02) 16.667%,rgba(11, 11, 11, 0.02) 16.667%, rgba(11, 11, 11, 0.02) 33.334%,rgba(162, 162, 162, 0.02) 33.334%, rgba(162, 162, 162, 0.02) 50.001000000000005%,rgba(171, 171, 171, 0.02) 50.001%, rgba(171, 171, 171, 0.02) 66.668%,rgba(119, 119, 119, 0.02) 66.668%, rgba(119, 119, 119, 0.02) 83.33500000000001%,rgba(106, 106, 106, 0.02) 83.335%, rgba(106, 106, 106, 0.02) 100.002%),linear-gradient(11deg, rgba(245, 245, 245, 0.01) 0%, rgba(245, 245, 245, 0.01) 16.667%,rgba(23, 23, 23, 0.01) 16.667%, rgba(23, 23, 23, 0.01) 33.334%,rgba(96, 96, 96, 0.01) 33.334%, rgba(96, 96, 96, 0.01) 50.001000000000005%,rgba(140, 140, 140, 0.01) 50.001%, rgba(140, 140, 140, 0.01) 66.668%,rgba(120, 120, 120, 0.01) 66.668%, rgba(120, 120, 120, 0.01) 83.33500000000001%,rgba(48, 48, 48, 0.01) 83.335%, rgba(48, 48, 48, 0.01) 100.002%),linear-gradient(27deg, rgba(106, 106, 106, 0.03) 0%, rgba(106, 106, 106, 0.03) 14.286%,rgba(203, 203, 203, 0.03) 14.286%, rgba(203, 203, 203, 0.03) 28.572%,rgba(54, 54, 54, 0.03) 28.572%, rgba(54, 54, 54, 0.03) 42.858%,rgba(75, 75, 75, 0.03) 42.858%, rgba(75, 75, 75, 0.03) 57.144%,rgba(216, 216, 216, 0.03) 57.144%, rgba(216, 216, 216, 0.03) 71.42999999999999%,rgba(39, 39, 39, 0.03) 71.43%, rgba(39, 39, 39, 0.03) 85.71600000000001%,rgba(246, 246, 246, 0.03) 85.716%, rgba(246, 246, 246, 0.03) 100.002%),linear-gradient(317deg, rgba(215, 215, 215, 0.01) 0%, rgba(215, 215, 215, 0.01) 16.667%,rgba(72, 72, 72, 0.01) 16.667%, rgba(72, 72, 72, 0.01) 33.334%,rgba(253, 253, 253, 0.01) 33.334%, rgba(253, 253, 253, 0.01) 50.001000000000005%,rgba(4, 4, 4, 0.01) 50.001%, rgba(4, 4, 4, 0.01) 66.668%,rgba(183, 183, 183, 0.01) 66.668%, rgba(183, 183, 183, 0.01) 83.33500000000001%,rgba(17, 17, 17, 0.01) 83.335%, rgba(17, 17, 17, 0.01) 100.002%),linear-gradient(128deg, rgba(119, 119, 119, 0.03) 0%, rgba(119, 119, 119, 0.03) 12.5%,rgba(91, 91, 91, 0.03) 12.5%, rgba(91, 91, 91, 0.03) 25%,rgba(45, 45, 45, 0.03) 25%, rgba(45, 45, 45, 0.03) 37.5%,rgba(182, 182, 182, 0.03) 37.5%, rgba(182, 182, 182, 0.03) 50%,rgba(243, 243, 243, 0.03) 50%, rgba(243, 243, 243, 0.03) 62.5%,rgba(162, 162, 162, 0.03) 62.5%, rgba(162, 162, 162, 0.03) 75%,rgba(190, 190, 190, 0.03) 75%, rgba(190, 190, 190, 0.03) 87.5%,rgba(148, 148, 148, 0.03) 87.5%, rgba(148, 148, 148, 0.03) 100%),linear-gradient(90deg, rgb(185, 139, 80),rgb(176, 26, 6))
                ]]>
            </x:String>
        </magic:CssGradientSource>
    </magic:GradientView.GradientSource>
</magic:GradientView>
```

And if we want to use the same from CSS:

```
.gradientStyledWithCss {
    background: linear-gradient(242deg, rgba(195, 195, 195, 0.02) 0%, rgba(195, 195, 195, 0.02) 16.667%,rgba(91, 91, 91, 0.02) 16.667%, rgba(91, 91, 91, 0.02) 33.334%,rgba(230, 230, 230, 0.02) 33.334%, rgba(230, 230, 230, 0.02) 50.001000000000005%,rgba(18, 18, 18, 0.02) 50.001%, rgba(18, 18, 18, 0.02) 66.668%,rgba(163, 163, 163, 0.02) 66.668%, rgba(163, 163, 163, 0.02) 83.33500000000001%,rgba(140, 140, 140, 0.02) 83.335%, rgba(140, 140, 140, 0.02) 100.002%),linear-gradient(152deg, rgba(151, 151, 151, 0.02) 0%, rgba(151, 151, 151, 0.02) 16.667%,rgba(11, 11, 11, 0.02) 16.667%, rgba(11, 11, 11, 0.02) 33.334%,rgba(162, 162, 162, 0.02) 33.334%, rgba(162, 162, 162, 0.02) 50.001000000000005%,rgba(171, 171, 171, 0.02) 50.001%, rgba(171, 171, 171, 0.02) 66.668%,rgba(119, 119, 119, 0.02) 66.668%, rgba(119, 119, 119, 0.02) 83.33500000000001%,rgba(106, 106, 106, 0.02) 83.335%, rgba(106, 106, 106, 0.02) 100.002%),linear-gradient(11deg, rgba(245, 245, 245, 0.01) 0%, rgba(245, 245, 245, 0.01) 16.667%,rgba(23, 23, 23, 0.01) 16.667%, rgba(23, 23, 23, 0.01) 33.334%,rgba(96, 96, 96, 0.01) 33.334%, rgba(96, 96, 96, 0.01) 50.001000000000005%,rgba(140, 140, 140, 0.01) 50.001%, rgba(140, 140, 140, 0.01) 66.668%,rgba(120, 120, 120, 0.01) 66.668%, rgba(120, 120, 120, 0.01) 83.33500000000001%,rgba(48, 48, 48, 0.01) 83.335%, rgba(48, 48, 48, 0.01) 100.002%),linear-gradient(27deg, rgba(106, 106, 106, 0.03) 0%, rgba(106, 106, 106, 0.03) 14.286%,rgba(203, 203, 203, 0.03) 14.286%, rgba(203, 203, 203, 0.03) 28.572%,rgba(54, 54, 54, 0.03) 28.572%, rgba(54, 54, 54, 0.03) 42.858%,rgba(75, 75, 75, 0.03) 42.858%, rgba(75, 75, 75, 0.03) 57.144%,rgba(216, 216, 216, 0.03) 57.144%, rgba(216, 216, 216, 0.03) 71.42999999999999%,rgba(39, 39, 39, 0.03) 71.43%, rgba(39, 39, 39, 0.03) 85.71600000000001%,rgba(246, 246, 246, 0.03) 85.716%, rgba(246, 246, 246, 0.03) 100.002%),linear-gradient(317deg, rgba(215, 215, 215, 0.01) 0%, rgba(215, 215, 215, 0.01) 16.667%,rgba(72, 72, 72, 0.01) 16.667%, rgba(72, 72, 72, 0.01) 33.334%,rgba(253, 253, 253, 0.01) 33.334%, rgba(253, 253, 253, 0.01) 50.001000000000005%,rgba(4, 4, 4, 0.01) 50.001%, rgba(4, 4, 4, 0.01) 66.668%,rgba(183, 183, 183, 0.01) 66.668%, rgba(183, 183, 183, 0.01) 83.33500000000001%,rgba(17, 17, 17, 0.01) 83.335%, rgba(17, 17, 17, 0.01) 100.002%),linear-gradient(128deg, rgba(119, 119, 119, 0.03) 0%, rgba(119, 119, 119, 0.03) 12.5%,rgba(91, 91, 91, 0.03) 12.5%, rgba(91, 91, 91, 0.03) 25%,rgba(45, 45, 45, 0.03) 25%, rgba(45, 45, 45, 0.03) 37.5%,rgba(182, 182, 182, 0.03) 37.5%, rgba(182, 182, 182, 0.03) 50%,rgba(243, 243, 243, 0.03) 50%, rgba(243, 243, 243, 0.03) 62.5%,rgba(162, 162, 162, 0.03) 62.5%, rgba(162, 162, 162, 0.03) 75%,rgba(190, 190, 190, 0.03) 75%, rgba(190, 190, 190, 0.03) 87.5%,rgba(148, 148, 148, 0.03) 87.5%, rgba(148, 148, 148, 0.03) 100%),linear-gradient(90deg, rgb(185, 139, 80),rgb(176, 26, 6));
}
```

```
<ContentPage.Resources>
    <StyleSheet Source="../Styles/LinearGradientsPage.css" />
</ContentPage.Resources>
...
<Button StyleClass="gradientStyledWithCss" />
```

Comment: This is a paid library. I wanted to do it using CSS

Comment: Thanks for the link, and yes I did searched a lot, but was not getting any specific css for button. And this also ask to a nuget package. I wanted to have CSS for button with gradient not by using any third party plugin. It would be great if can provide specific to the topic

Comment: The Second link I added just have a look threw there it adds a background gradient Just use that for the button, They are rather adaptable. Els the Gradient background repository is there to